# PyQT chamando arquivo criado pelo QtDesigner

Tags: python, interface, pyqt

Desenvolvi uma janela no PyQt com template  Dialog with Buttons Right porem ao chamar na minha classe principal me retorna um erro de atributo. Eu vi no video do YT que o cara utilizou o Main Window como template e ele apenas instaciou class Main_principal(QtGui.QMainWindow): ja tentei fazer o mesmo para o meu template e nada.
Segue o meu codigo

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui
from sistema import Ui_Dialog
class Main_principal(QtGui.QDialogwithButtonsRight):
   def _init_(self):
   QtGui.QDialogwithButtonsRight.__init__(self)
   self.ui = Ui_Dialog()
   self.ui.setupUi(self)

app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
programa = Main()
programa.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

e me retorna o seguinte erro:

> AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'QDialogwithButtonsRight'

Comment: Atenção com a identação ao colcar código - O seu está com erro de sintaxe. Note que você não deve ficar tentando identa rmanualmente o código após colar - selecione todo o código colado e pressione o botão de formatação marcado como `{}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bom, existe uma série de erros nesse código, então vamos por etapas;

**Primeiro**, O erro é que em `PyQt5`, `QApplication` não está contido em `QtGui`, em `PyQt4` era assim,
mas depois foi movido para `QtWidgets`,

**Segundo**, **QDialogwithButtonsRight** é um Método que não existe!, e não me recordo de nenhum semelhante, até fui verificar a documentação pra ver se encontrava, mas nao achei nada, então não sei oque você quis dizer.

**Terceiro**, a classe `Main_principal` tem que Herdar o objeto `QtWidgets.QDialog`, que não foi importado.

**Quarto**, a classe inicializadora `__init__`, tem dois underlines e no seu exemplo só existe um.

**Quinto**, Você não chamou a superclasse `super()`.

**Sexto**, em `programa = Main()` o nome da classe que é atribuido a váriavel,
então seria;  `programa = Main_principal()`

Então concluindo com essas mudanças no código esse seria um resultado funcional:

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
from sistema import Ui_Dialog

class Main_principal(QtWidgets.QDialog):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.ui = Ui_Dialog()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)



app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
programa = Main_principal()
programa.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Espero ter ajudado,  Boa Sorte nos Estudos.